# Context-free grammar for VBA

Tags: python, context-free-grammar, ply

I'm trying to scan and parse VBA (visual basic for application) code for a school assignment.

I'm using Python PLY lex and yacc modules. Right now I'm just trying to get variable declaration and assignments to work as a proof of concept.
My preliminary grammar understands a variable declaration OR an assignment. As soon as I put a newline (\n) character in there and add another statement it doesn't understand anything. 
ie: In the code in the gist, if you remove "a = 3" from the string at line 92, it will work fine, and insert an Identifier in the identifier list.

I handle newline characters in the scanner, so I think there's something wrong with my grammar definition, but can't figure it out.

The grammar is basically this:

```
statement : declaration
          | assignment

declaration : DIM IDENTIFIER AS TYPE

assignment : IDENTIFIER ASSIGN BOOLEAN
           | IDENTIFIER ASSIGN DOUBLE
           | IDENTIFIER ASSIGN INT
```

Note that IDENTIFIER, ASSIGN, BOOLEAN, DOUBLE, INT DIM, AS and TYPE are all tokens defined in the lex module.

I've created a [gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/clsk/22c386695dd1ddb7ca75) which is at: https://gist.github.com/clsk/22c386695dd1ddb7ca75

Comment: That's a grammar for a single statement. Why do you expect it to work with multiple statements? Nowhere is there a production which indicate that multiple statements are legal input.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rici wrote:

> That's a grammar for a single statement. Why do you expect it to work with multiple statements? Nowhere is there a production which indicate that multiple statements are legal input.

The OP wrote:

> Indeed that was the issue. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))